# SQL change attribute_set

Tags: sql, attributes

I'm working on an migration from M1 to M2 and I need to change the attribute set in M1 db before migration.
In M1 there has been used more than 7 attributes sets and that does not make sence anymore.

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_entity` 
SET `attribute_set_id` = '4' 
WHERE `catalog_product_entity`.`entity_id` = 610;
```

My question, that I need help for, is that I would like to change the all at once insteed of doing it one by one.

Above makes an update with entity_id 610 to set attribute_set_id to 4.

How do I change all on one query where the existing attribute_set_id is 10?
And I would like to change it to 4 for all products with the attribute_set_id 10.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_entity`
    SET `attribute_set_id` = 4
    WHERE attribute_set_id = 10;
```

Comment: Yes sir. You made my day :)